# Is there any API in android for user management?

Tags: java, android, user-management

I am developing an application in Android that can be used by many groups of users. I want to manage my users' access to each part of my application.

I know there is a user management structure in .Net. I want to know if there is something similar in Java or Android for user management and access controls or I have to implement this structure completely by myself?

Comment: Not sure, but maybe AccountManager class will be helpful: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean multiple users on the device itself?  Multi-user support was only added with 4.2, which means that you can't expect it even on most new devices yet.  And there's no real support for blocking access, except for on the filesystem.

Or do you mean that your app has a web service they'll need to log into and that parts of it are only supposed to be accessed by certain  user groups?  If so, no.  But that's more a server feature than a client feature anyway-  never trust the client to verify itself, that's how you get security breeches.

Comment: I mean the second one. Where can I find a tutorial for implementing that structure in my application manually?